VBA Macro Compare Workbooks Issue to Report Unique Differences Only
I'm hoping this great community might be able to help me adjust a piece of VBA code to finish off what I am trying to achieve
I am running a project where we are building out a physical data model iteratively and a new version is being produced on a workbook with multiple worksheets each month. It is anticipated that new lines will be inserted and amendments made to text fields in the worksheets on the New workbook as it evolves.
Public Sub CompareTwoWorkbooks()
  Dim WS As Worksheet
  Workbooks.Add
  For Each WS In Workbooks("D365 Fields Physical Data Model - Existing.xlsm").Worksheets
    Call CompareWorksheets(WS, Workbooks("D365 Fields Physical Data Model - New.xlsm").Worksheets(WS.Name))
  Next
End Sub

Public Sub CompareWorksheets(ByVal WS1 As Worksheet, _
                             ByVal WS2 As Worksheet)
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim R1 As Range
Dim R2 As Range
  ' add the corresponding worksheet for the results
  Worksheets.Add.Name = WS1.Name
  Range("A1:D1").Value = Array("Address", "Difference", WS1.Parent.Name, WS2.Parent.Name)
  Range("A2").Select
  For iRow = 1 To Application.Max(WS1.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row, _
                      WS2.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row)
    For iCol = 1 To Application.Max(WS1.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column, _
                      WS2.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column)
      Set R1 = WS1.Cells(iRow, iCol)
      Set R2 = WS2.Cells(iRow, iCol)
      ' compare the types to avoid getting VBA type mismatch errors.
      If (TypeName(R1.Value) <> TypeName(R2.Value)) Then
        Call LogDifference(R1.Address, "Type", R1.Value, R2.Value)
      ElseIf (R1.Value <> R2.Value) Then
        If (TypeName(R1.Value) = "Double") Then
          If (Abs(R1.Value - R2.Value) > R1.Value * 10 ^ (-12)) Then
            Call LogDifference(R1.Address, "Double", R1.Value, R2.Value)
          End If
        Else
            Call LogDifference(R1.Address, "Value", R1.Value, R2.Value)
        End If
      End If
      ' record formulae without leading "=" to avoid them being evaluated
      If (R1.HasFormula = True) Then
        If (R2.HasFormula = True) Then
          If (R1.Formula <> R2.Formula) Then
            Call LogDifference(R1.Address, "Formula", Mid(R1.Formula, 2), Mid(R2.Formula, 2))
          End If
        Else
          Call LogDifference(R1.Address, "Formula", Mid(R1.Formula, 2), "**no formula**")
        End If
      Else
        If (R2.HasFormula = True) Then
          Call LogDifference(R1.Address, "Formula", "**no formula**", Mid(R2.Formula, 2))
        End If
      End If
      If (R1.NumberFormat <> R2.NumberFormat) Then
        Call LogDifference(R1.Address, "NumberFormat", R1.NumberFormat, R2.NumberFormat)
      End If
    Next iCol
  Next iRow
  With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns
    .AutoFit
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
  End With
End Sub

Public Sub LogDifference(ByVal Address As String, _
                         ByVal What As String, _
                         ByVal V1 As Variant, _
                         ByVal V2 As Variant)
  ActiveCell.Resize(1, 4).Value = Array(Address, What, V1, V2)
  ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
  If ActiveCell.Row = Rows.Count Then
    Call MsgBox("Too many differences", vbExclamation)
    End
  End If
End Sub


I have picked up this great piece of VBA code to compare the two workbooks (Existing & New) and output the differences to a third workbook, however, where a new row is inserted on the New workbook, it will report all subsequent rows as differences, even though there is no effective change to the values between existing and new, albeit it is now on a lower row. I have attached a screen grab of the three workbooks to highlight the example I am seeing
Is there a way to amend the macro so that it only produces the output difference for the row in question?
I have attached a screen grab of the three workbooks to highlight how it is being shown on the output difference workbook

I am not seeing a screen cap, upload one to http://imgur.com and link to it. The easiest would be to only add content at the end, instead of inserting rows here and there. That said, is there a way to differentiate rows that have been inserted from rows that have been modified?

Unless you have some fixed unique value for each row, which persists through the edit/insert process, there's no way to know which pairs of lines should be compared.  You could add an id to each line so you know what needs to be compared with what.
